# C++ to C# Callback Struct Marshalling

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

i'm having some trouble in my Project.

I'm using a c++ .dll compiled ( i have no chance to change it, recompile or modify it) i have the .h where there are some (bad documented) info.
This dll is used to interact with a device connected via USB. The device is properly configurated and using the function the dll provide i have the absoulute certainty that it's properly answering to the dll call.
Th marshalling from c++ and c# is quite easy until i have to use Callback to register to some event thrown by the device.

This is the significative part of the c++ .h i have to use in c#
(first and second event are fake names)

```
//First Event data
typedef struct tagFIRST_EVENT {
    int a; 
    int b; 
    int c;
} FIRST_EVENT;

//SecondEvent data
typedef struct tagSECOND_EVENT {
    int e; 
    int f; 
} SECOND_EVENT;

//first event callback?
typedef void (CALLBACK *FIRTS_EVENT_LISTENER)(FIRST_EVENT *event, void *userData);  

//second event callback?
typedef void (CALLBACK *SECOND_EVENT_LISTENER)(SECOND_EVENT *event, void *userData);


//Register to all given callback in the struct LISTENER
int WINAPI RegisterEvents(LISTENER *listenerGroup );

typedef struct tagLISTENER {
    FIRTS_EVENT_LISTENER first_listener;
    SECOND_EVENT_LISTENER second_listener;
    void * userData;
} LISTENER;
```

I have some trouble marshalling to have the c++ .dll call my c# functions i have defined to handle the event thrown by the device.

I've followed many example found but i have i could not be able to use those functionality in the proper way. Basically the c# application crash without any further info (i think because the error is in the c++ dll and i'm not able to catch the error).

Can i have an example of implementation given the code snippet above?

I searched deep and i have found only similar question but no one of those could help me.
I'm here for any clarification, Thanks in advice!

Comment: You didn't mention what trouble do you have...

Comment: I cut that party, sorry. I will Edit the post to answer your question.

Comment: Do you keep the instance of the handler's delegate, until no more callbacks are expected?

Comment: How can it be done? I saw some example in c++ but i thought it was not the point (probably i thought worng) can i have a little example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know how much marshaling you have done, so I assume that you did create binary-compatible types in C# for `FirstEvent` and `SecondEvent` data types.

For the function pointers, all you need is `IntPtr`.

After all that (which I'll expand if you didn't create the binary-compatible types), all you have to do is create a delegate which itself is binary compatible:

```
delegate void FirstEventListener(ref FirstEvent firstEvent, IntPtr userData);
delegate void SecondEventListener(ref SecondEvent secondEvent, IntPtr userData);
```

then, you can create a delegate instance, for the actual handler, and use `[Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at4fb09f.ASPX)` to get a pointer (as `IntPtr`),

**Rember to keep that delegate instance alive (ie, hold a reference to it) as long as the callback could be called.**

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will test and see!! I will post some come of my c# solution if i can't fix this.

Comment: Solved thanks a lot, i was doing one BAD mistake.
The two struct  (FirstEvent and SecondEvent) was not bassed by ref.
Thanks again!